# How do I get the ElementHandle's class name when using Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to get an ElementHandle's class name using Puppeteer... is it possible? Am I using the wrong approach? In this jsBin is part of my code, so you can understand what I am trying to achieve.

```
CriticalCssPlugin.prototype.load = function( page, src ) {
  return page.goto( src, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' } )
    .then( () => {
      return page
        .$$( '*' )
        .then( elements => {
          return Promise.all( elements.map( element => {
            return element.boundingBox()
          } ) )
            .then( positions => {
              let visible = positions.filter( ( rect, index ) => {
                if ( !rect ) {
                  return rect
                }

                rect.element = elements[ index ]

                return this.isAnyPartOfElementInViewport( rect, page.viewport() )
              } )

              this.getClasses( visible )
            } )
        } )
    } )
}

CriticalCssPlugin.prototype.getClasses = function( visibles ) {
  Promise.all( visibles.map( visible => {
    return visible.element.getProperty( '' )
  } ) )
    .then( classes => {
      console.log(classes);
    } )
}

CriticalCssPlugin.prototype.isAnyPartOfElementInViewport = function( rect, viewport ) {
  const windowHeight = viewport.height
  const windowWidth = viewport.width
  const vertInView = ( rect.y <= windowHeight ) && ( ( rect.y + rect.height ) >= 0 )
  const horInView = ( rect.x <= windowWidth ) && ( ( rect.x + rect.width ) >= 0 )

  return ( vertInView && horInView )
}
```

https://jsbin.com/kuzejoluji/edit?js,output

Thank you :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Going to drop this here since this page is currently first result searching for "elementhandle class name"*

From the [docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.7.0&show=api-elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname), you should just be able to the following

```
const el = await page.$('.myElement')
const className = await el.getProperty('className')

// alternatively,
// page.$('.myElement')
//    .then(el => el.getProperty('className'))
//    .then(className => ... )
```

Comment: In newer APIs you also need to call `jsonValue()` because `getProperty()` returns a JSHandle (see [docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.5.0&show=api-elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname)). To get the class: `const className = await (await el.getProperty('className')).jsonValue()`

Answer (score 10):

jimmyjoy's answer is right but this may help others use the elementHandle

```
  page.$(el) // This grabs the element (returns a elementHandle)
    .then((el) => el.getProperty("className")) // Returns a jsHandle of that property
    .then((cn) => cn.jsonValue()) // This converts the className jsHandle to a space delimitedstring       
    .then((classNameString) => classNameString.split(" ") // Splits into array
    .then((x) => console.log(x)
```

Which would log an array of classes

Note: when i tried to do a .split on the end of jsonValue() it didn't work as i believe the promise isn't resolved at that point so `cn.jsonValue().split(" ")` wont work

---

References

[List of properties on elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

[Puppeteer docs for ElementHandle](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlegetpropertypropertyname)

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that helps in parts, but it was good enough to me. I've got the class name acessing `ElementHandle._remoteObject.description`.
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: After reading your post, `ElementHandle._remoteObject.value` is what ended up working perfectly for me, in my Puppeteer scripts. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

you can get the element variable and use evaluate function like that:

```
const element = await page.$(".some-class"); // for ids you can write "#some-id"
const className = await page.evaluate(el => el.className, element);
console.log('className', className) // here you can get the class name
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this function

```js
// JS
export async function elementHasClass(el, className) {
  const classNames = (
    await (await el.getProperty('className')).jsonValue()
  ).split(/\s+/);

  return classNames.includes(className);
}

// TS
export async function elementHasClass(
  el: ElementHandle,
  className: string,
): Promise<boolean> {
  const classNames = (
    await (await el.getProperty('className')).jsonValue()
  ).split(/\s+/);

  return classNames.includes(className);
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, although the type in `jsonValue<string>()` seems unnecessary with Puppeteer 22.0.0. I had to use it with `jsonValue()` to remove the warning in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

> This is what i did:

```
let posts = await page.$$(".postContainer .upvote");

for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
// log class name
        console.log(await (await posts[i].getProperty('className')).jsonValue());

// click upvotes on posts
        await codes[i].click();
    }
```